# How to change the state of login component after user Logged in

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, setstate

I have login component

```
class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showPassword : false,
            buttonText : 'login',
            username : null,
            password: null,
            isSignedUp: false // <-- initialize the signup state as false
        }
        this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    }

    async login() {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("email", this.state.username);
        formData.append("password", this.state.password);
        return axios({
            method: "post",
            url: `${BaseURL}/login`,
            data: formData,
        })
        .then((response) => {
            new Promise((resolve) => this.setState({ isSignedUp: true }));
        })

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        if (this.state.isSignedUp) {
            return <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/panel" }} />;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick = {this.login}> Login </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

and my `panel` is a functional component when I want to logOut from `panel` and `redirect` to `login` the `state` of `this.state.isSignedUp` still have `true` value, how cant I change that befor I got to `login` component

**Update**

I added the `then` in `Axios` call, to show you how I changed the `isSignedUp` state

Comment: Are you just asking how to update the `this.state.isSignedUp` value in the `axios` Promise chain? Or something else? Or how to set it back to false when the other component logs the user out? Seems you'll need to lift your state to a common ancestor to both components. We need a bit more context. Where is the `isSignedUp` state ever set `true`?

Comment: @DrewReese I update my code AND  yes this is my question `how to set it back to false when the other component logs the user out`

Answer (score 1):

Right now `isSignedUp` is a local state of `Login`.
You need to create state that is shared between `Login` and `Panel` components.

You can use [`context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) API or a parent component that holds the state and does the routing between these two components

Comment: Please create a [mcve] codesandbox. You probably already have a parent component like `App` that renders these component. You should put the loggedIn state there.

Comment: sorry i dont have time for making that but id you show me how or an example